# Unknown apps proposed when sharing files

Tags: ipad, file-sharing, files.app

I have a music project that's been going since last week and I want to share one of the Garage Band files with my group.

It works just fine but when I see the options to share the project as a soundfile through an app, I see an app that I have never installed and I have never gone to on any of my devices, SoundCloud.

[image]

This unknown app has just popped up between other installed apps like that! I have never seen this app being in the sharing options before.

Of course, I have checked in the App Library to be sure I haven't got this app. I searched for "SoundCloud" and for "Sound Cloud" but no result. I have also checked in Settings, searching for the same words but nothing. So I am sure I haven't got this app installed somewhere and am therefore more astonished to see it like that.

[image]

Also, this does not only happen on .band files, it happens when trying to share every kind of file from Files app and not from an other app. It only happens on my iPad 6th gen running iPadOS 16.2.

I have tried clicking it but nothing happens.

My question is : **Why does this app popped up in my sharing options so suddenly?**

Answer (score 1):

SoundCloud is built into the garage band app as a destination so you don’t need any sort of app to send your song there.

Files isn’t a full app and it pulls share destinations from the owner of the file, so if you try to share a PDF or Pages doc, you might not see SoundCloud but if you share a document type GarageBand claims, files uses the GarageBand sharing destinations.

Comment: Soundcloud is like YouTube for audio. It's just a 'convenience' addition for members to be able to upload directly. YouTube has similar convenience entries in iMovie/Final Cut Pro.